# TV show, Humanoid Aliens spaceship crashs in Alaska, Half escape, Half are captured

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

TV series broadcast in USA, Probably from 1990-2010. Set in modern times, in English.

Spaceship full of humanoid aliens crashes in Alaska or northern Canada in the middle of winter... Earth radar saw the crash and sent out the military to "rescue" the survivor of the crash. About half/two-thirds, escaped before the Military arrived. I think the ship had about 150-200 aliens on board, but only 40-50 were captured (Mostly those injured in the crash).

The crash happened in the 1960s-70s, and now 30-40 years later, the captured aliens are still being held in prisoners in an isolated military base. If I recall correctly they have aged very little.

Meanwhile the ones who have escaped have blended into society and worked they way up in power/position/authority in business and politically.

I believe one of (if not The leader) was one of those who was captured and is an elderly woman. She is keeping the ones who were captured from causing trouble or making waves while coffined. But I don't think any of the prisoner were revealing anything to the humans despite being questioned for years.

I think the ones who escaped were working on how to contact home, but some of them were getting frustrated that their companions were still being held prisoners and were agitating their leaders on the outside to do something about getting them out.

I can recall 2 scenes I think were in this series. At one point a bunch of people gather in an auditorium or movie theater. It is then revealed that ALL of them are the aliens who escaped the crash. They are having discussions/arguments about how to proceed.

Another scene I remember is the US President(?) is giving a speech out doors somewhere, and hijackers/terrorists grab a airline jet and it is going to crash into where the speech is taking place. (Everyone there at the location is GOING to get killed) [I think the VP left just before the crash he may have been involved in arranging the crash.]

The aliens decide they Have to reveal themselves/capabilities. They open a portal right in front of the jet and it flies into it and is teleported about 100 miles away where it does a belly flop in the desert.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [*The Event*](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Event) (2010).

> At the end of World War II the aliens crash into Alaska. Some of them are taken by the United States. Others get away. They stay hidden taking normal jobs. Some of them are helping the aliens get back home. President Elias Martinez decides to release the aliens. However as he is holding a press conference the an airplane attempts to kill him. It does not work because the Aliens transport the plane to a desert in Arizona. The aliens that were being held told him that they were the only ones. However that was not true. Soon they escape the prison and attempt to kill the president. They have the Vice-President help with this.

Comment: YES!! That is it. I recognize the older woman leader. And the location of the Speech where the jet is going to crash.

Comment: [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)